# In php, cycle through array (returned from an api) for a specific description

Tags: php, arrays, api

For a small project i am doing, i am grabbing some data from an api.
the data returned is decoded as follows:
under members, the first number (in this case: 65385)  is the members id.

If a members status is ok, i want to return this ID, and the members name.
I am able to return the members name, but not sure how to also get the ID

```
"members": {
    "65385": {
        "name": "phpnewb",
        "days_active": 705,
        "last_action": {
            "status": "active",
            "timestamp": "",
            "relative": "51 minutes ago"
        },
        "status": {
            "description": "Okay",
            "details": "",
            "state": "Okay",
            "color": "green",
            "until": 0
        },
```

Now what i want is:
if under status -> Description it says "Okay"  i want to return the members id & members name
which would id: 65385 & name: phpnewb  in this case.

Now i have tried doing this by (the name part) like this (with $idcall_array beeing the decoded data):

```
foreach ($idcall_array['members'] as $member) {
    
    if ($member['status']['description'] == "Okay") {
        $name = $member['name'];
        echo $name;
        echo "</br>";
    }


}
```

This returns the name as expected,  i just have no idea how to also get the id, with a var_dump on members i don't see the ID anymore

I am not experienced with these things.

help is appreciated

edit:
when doing a var_dump($members)
i get:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "phpnewb"
```

i asume the array(5) is the int/number i need, but dont know how to extract this.

Comment: You need to catch the key of the foreach: `foreach ($idcall_array['members'] as $id => $member) {`

Comment: Thank you, that solved it, if you place that as the answer i will mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the key of the [foreach](https://php.net/foreach), in your case, the id of the member :

```
foreach ($idcall_array['members'] as $id => $member) {
    echo $id . ' : ' . $member['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

NB: A correct break-line tag is `<br>` in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($idcall_array['members'] as $id => $member) {
    if ($member['status']['description'] == "Okay") {
        $name = $member['name'];
        echo $name;
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i will wait an hour to see if syscall will post this same answer (since he already answered it in a comment) if not, i will accept your answer :)

Comment: sure @Phpnewb, lets give him the first priority